# To print simple struct or enum, derived from Debug or explicit fmt::Display implementation?

Tags: rust

I have a simple `enum` or `struct` and want to print. We know that being derived from `Debug` automatically enables a quick printing without explicit an implementation of `fmt::Display`. But you can still implement `Display` for printing it.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyDataType {
    INVALID = 0,
    TYPE1 = 1,
    TYPE2 = 2,
}

let my_type: MyDataType = ...;

// This won't compile.
println!("{my_type}");
```

```
   |
10 |     println!("{my_type}");
   |                ^^^^^^^ `MyDataType` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `MyDataType`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
```

So, there're two approaches to make it work:

```
// Simply using Debug
#[derive(Debug)]

// Or, have your own Display implementation
impl fmt::Display for MyDataType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            MyDataType::INVALID => write!(f, "INVALID"),
            MyDataType::TYPE1 => write!(f, "TYPE1"),
            MyDataType::TYPE2 => write!(f, "TYPE2"),
        }
    }
}
```

What are the tradeoffs between these two approaches? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I see only one approach.

Comment: If the `Debug` implementation is fine for `Display` then just derive `Debug` and have the `Display` impl delegate to it: `Debug::fmt(self, f)`

Comment: Edited with "two" approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to imply there's only two options, derive `Debug` or manually implement `Display`, which is not the case at all, you can do both (or neither) and for different reasons. `Debug` and `Display` are different traits for different purposes; [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) is developer-centric while [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) is user-centric.

If the derived implementation is good enough for developers, great! You can use that! If not, you can implement it manually. And if that is also good enough for users, great! You can defer to the `Debug` implementation when implementing `Display` as @cdhowie suggested in the comments. If not, you can implement that manually as well.

I don't see any "tradeoffs" to really consider here. If the derived implementation isn't what you want, then don't use it. Its up to you what you need and how it should be formatted.